# Artifactory maven virtual repository 404s

Tags: maven, sbt, artifactory

I am trying to use a maven virtual repository that is linked up to an SBT local repository to resolve dependencies, but I keep getting 404s when I try to download the artifacts. They are listed fine on the UI, but right clicking on the artifacts and hitting "Download" give me a 404 error. Has anyone run into this problem. We're using JFrogs cloud hosted version of Artifactory on AWS. Our virtual Gradle repository is setup the same way and works as expected ...

mvn install output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.example:myjar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.220 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-13T10:41:55-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-app: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.example:myjar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in https://example.jfrog.io/example/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are differences between snapshot policies between your local repositories referenced from the virtual one.

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-17521